# python selenium chrome alert no callable?

Tags: python, selenium

**i write a script to login in router and upgrade fireware, but chrome pop up a alter, and selenium  code can't get alert info? can anyone help me?**

```
#coding:utf-8
import sys
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('http://192.168.1.1')

.
.
.

status_frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//frame[@src="/admin/status.asp"]')

driver.switch_to.frame(status_frame)
file_upload = driver.find_element_by_name('binary')
submit = driver.find_element_by_name('send')

file_upload.send_keys('E:\upgrate_fw\firmware\ISCOMHT803-DR_T_RC01_SYSTEM_3.0.15(a)_20170103')
submit.click()


alert = driver.switch_to.alert()
time.sleep(3)
print alert.text
```

The result:

> C:\Python27\python.exe E:/router/ISCOM-HT803.py Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "E:/router/ISCOM-HT803.py", line 43, in 
>       alert = driver.switch_to.alert() TypeError: 'Alert' object is not callable
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

[image: show alert dialog after submit.click()]

Comment: after submit.click()  done, then will run this js <script>
function sendClicked()
{
 if (document.password.binary.value=="") {
  alert("选定的文件不能为空!");
  document.password.binary.focus();
  return false;
 }

 if (!confirm('您确定要更新此软件?'))
  return false;
 else
  return true;
}

</script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alert object is not callable? Then you should stop calling it. So modify

```
browser.switch_to.alert().accept()
```

to

```
browser.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

(So remove the () after alert).

Comment: Yes,  alert is a property , not a method. i try it with your tip, it run good. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.switch_to.alert is deprecated.
```

it is `switch_to_alert()`  not `switch_to.alert()`

Also consider doing `Alert(driver).accept()` or `Alert(driver).dismiss()`if you have only one alert and want to get it out of your way.